# Why is javascript not checking my checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am trying to test a simple header checkbox checks all checkboxes in a table.

The test is below:

```
scenario 'select all enrolments', js: true do
  check 'all_enrolment_presentations'
  expect(page).to have_css('.enrolment-presentation-listing input[type="checkbox"]:checked', count: 1)
end
```

This fails, however if I change the scenario a bit to

```
scenario 'select all enrolments', js: true do
  sleep 3
  check 'all_enrolment_presentations'
  expect(page).to have_css('.enrolment-presentation-listing input[type="checkbox"]:checked', count: 1)
end
```

It works.

I have tested a couple of other selectors and they all pretty much have the same affect. I do not want to have to add sleep statements to get stuff like this to pass. I must be doing something incorrect.

When I run the test without the sleep clause, it seems to find the control (it gets highlighted), but it isn't checked. See screenshot for what I mean.

[image]

My question is why is this happening and how can I fix my issue?

Note I am using rails 4.2.4 and capybara 2.5.0

Comment: What JS is bound to the select all checkbox? My guess would be it's a race condition between you checking the box and the JS initializing it. You could also try clicking on the box rather than checking it. find(...).click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation the bug was actually caused by upgrading selenium-webdriver from version 2.45.0 to 2.48.1. I haven't had enough time to investigate the root cause within the gem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until capybara to perform click operation.

So,

---

**1**. Use `sleep`

example `sleep 5` with wait for 5 seconds

---

**2**. Change default wait time in capybara using

```
 `Capybara.default_wait_time = some_value`
```

Comment: The default time is already set. Using sleep is not really a great solution since it causes your tests to wait the extra sleep time. This capybara function shouldn't require any magic to get it working.